# Latency in transaction confirmation is usual?

Tags: transaction, confirmation, reattach, promote

I sent some transactions to the IOTA Tangle.
However, according to thetangle.org website, they are not confirmed yet. You can see one of them here :

https://thetangle.org/transaction/EERZPPJFNDZRC9OFBX9QQNHRPK9JLBIAUED9LQQPHXXB9OJITMPWCYFSXRCWACHZXSZSWXXWIPDSA9999

As you can see in this transaction information, I promoted it several times. Also, I reattached and replayed it, but no result.

Is there a solution for this problem? And is it possible a transaction never get confirmed? If so, it seems to be a significant issue in IOTA, isn't it?

I can put my Javascript code here, if you need.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution is to reattach and/or promote it again and again.

Yes it is possible that a transaction is never confirmed. It may for instance be ending up in a parasite chain or other non-confirmed sidechain.
This is a very often the case and of no concern for the general iota network topology. It's not a bug, it's by design!

https://thetangle.org/transaction/XBIBDARYPCKKNRNBJZUTYDZQROUTPOWWSSTSOYAOCOXPUWUHZFTKTSWKQVROEMYNNDCSUHMXACZSZ9999

I confirmed it using www.iotareatta.ch

Comment: Thank you, I reattached / promoted this transaction several times, however it is not yet confirmed: https://thetangle.org/transaction/EERZPPJFNDZRC9OFBX9QQNHRPK9JLBIAUED9LQQPHXXB9OJITMPWCYFSXRCWACHZXSZSWXXWIPDSA9999